# Following code produces error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Summary :**

This code is in external javascipt file that include in html file, i am facing error when `<a href='#' class='btn btn-"+idinc+"' id='opener' onclick='sendJson('"+str+"')'>Book</a>` is clicked function called properly and error occured.

**Script :**

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  var url = "http://localhost/json/ticket.json";

  $("#search-btn").click(function() {
    $.getJSON(url, function(obj) {
      var idinc = 1;
      var str = "";
      $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
        //$('#result-input .flight_no').val()=value.status;
        var status = value.status;
        $("#search_result").append(
                        "<div class='row' id='result-input-"+idinc+"'>  
<div class='flight_no'><p id='flight-no-"+idinc+"'>"+value.flightNo+"</p></div> 
<div class='flight_date'> <p id='departure-time-"+idinc+"'>Deptr: "+value.departureTime+"</p><p id='arrival-time-"+idinc+"'>arrival: "+value.arrivalTime+"</p></div><div class='flight_date'><p id='from-"+idinc+"'>From: "+value.fromAirport+"</p><p id='to-"+idinc+"'>To: "+value.toAirport+"</p></div>   
<div class='flight_book'><a href='#' class='btn btn-"+idinc+"' id='opener' onclick='sendJson('"+str+"')'>Book</a></div> 
</div>");
        idinc=idinc+1;

      });
    });
  });


});
```

Function that will call on click. This function is in html file:

```
<script>
  function sendJson(mystr) {
    alert(mystr);

  }
</script>
```

Comment: This code looks fine - executing without any errors. Maybe your .json file has an syntax error?

Comment: Yeah, the script is good, and the produced HTML is valid.
Can you provide a piece of the JSON you are using ?
It might be a problem with `sendJson(mystr)`

Comment: thanks a lot for your help i solved the problem, the problem is in <a href="#" > onclick function in adding attribute. correct syntax is like this:            <a href='#' class='btn btn-"+idinc+"' id='opener' onclick=sendJson('"+value.flightNo+"'>Book</a>

Comment: @RohitJindal: while editing to improve the clarity of posts is appreciated, note that salutations like "help needed" and "thanks" are considered to be unnecessary and should not be added. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776/2074608 for more information. Thanks!

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy, Thanks ! I agree with you and will take care from now that not to use these words again in the posts.

Comment: @RohitJindal: I originally downvoted this post based on the urgent begging at the end. Thanks to Qantas I find that you put this in - it's worth bearing in mind that if the OP is made to seem to be requesting "immediate" help of volunteers, he or she might be downvoted for apparent impatience. Please read [this community discussion on the matter](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495) (I have removed my downvote).